# Elasticsearch Securing the connection

Tags: docker, security, elasticsearch

i am (desperately) new to elasticsearch (*7.9.0*) and i currently have a cluster with two nodes running.
After a lot of effort it is performing as i would like it to.

It is running on docker and also has an *nginx* in front of it to route the traffic to it since it is being accessed directly from my website (angular 10).
The elasticsearch is being used as well from my *laravel* backend directly through the docker container name so that is secure (i guess).

My problem now is that i cannot find or understand a way to secure the http access from outside docker (eg the normal website).

Going via *Laravel* is an option but this is too slow for my purpose.
Is there a way i can securely have http access to the elasticsearch from the web?

Also, is there a way i can restrict the actions to read only actions?
If you need more info to help out please let me know as i am not knowledgable on what is important here and what not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a *front-end* and is run in your user's web browser. **If Angular can somehow reach your Elasticsearch instance, everyone can do so.** No matter what. You can try to obscure it as many as you want, but if there is direct exposure to Elasticsearch, it will be reachable.

So you have to either assume this fact, or go the slow way and proxy the requests to Laravel, so it can verify that the information requested is actually available for the user performing the request.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i created a different PHP Proxy where i allow only the actions i really need to. I built it on Slim4 so the speed is definitely ok. I was hoping there was a way to not have that but for now it seems to be working pretty decent. thank you